# windows net user command to work with network service

Tags: windows, batch, user-accounts

This might be a trivial question but I was wondering if it was possible to use the `net user` command in windows to give back useful information on the "NT Authority\Network Service" user.  I have tried `net user "NT Authority\Network Service"` along with multiple variants of this but the command just spits out the usage info.  The reason I am doing this is I have a batch script where a user enters in a user name and I check to see if that user is already on the computer using `net user`.  If the user is present, nothing is done.  If the user is not present, I create the user.  I would like the user to be able to enter the network service user or the system user and still get the desired result.  I thought I had gotten this to work before but cant seem to find how I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Net User` won't show you those users, because they are not (regular) user accounts.

[From MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The NetworkService account is a predefined local account used by the
>   service control manager. This account is not recognized by the
>   security subsystem, so you cannot specify its name in a call to the
>   LookupAccountName function.

You can't use `Net User` to make an account named "NT Authority\Network Service" (or alike) anyway, so I'm not sure what your concern is. :)

Comment: Thanks! That answered my question.  I am not exactly worried about `net user` creating the network service somehow, I am more concerned with my script giving a false reading in regards to it saying the user does not exist when it does.  Since there is nothing I can do with regards to `net user`, I will just do something else.